# Override the start recording event in Youtube APIs

Tags: youtube-api, webcam

I am trying to develop a web application in which user can record his/her video using the webcam and upload it to youtube.

I would like to incorporate a feature in which video recording starts automatically. User need not press the start button(Ofcourse we need to take the permission to access the webcam). Once he/she allows the webcam access, the video recording should automatically start after 30 seconds.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m afraid that Youtube APIs does not provide that functionality. You need to build your own custom video recorder for that.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget